# javascript перебор двумерного массива n+1

Tags: javascript, html, css, массивы

есть такой код:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
 #game {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background: orangered;
}

.block {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
  </style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="game"></div>
 <script>
    var kvadratiki = [];
    pole();
    var i;
    var j;
    function pole() {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        kvadratiki[i]=[];
        for (var j=0; j<3; j++) {
            kvadratiki[i][j] = document.getElementById('game').innerHTML+='<div class="block"></div>';
        };  

    };
};

var hod = 0;

    document.getElementById('game').onclick = function(event){
        console.log(event);
        if (event.target.className == 'block'){
            if (hod%2==0) {
                event.target.innerHTML = 'x';
            }
            else {
                event.target.innerHTML = '0';
            }
            hod++;
            checkWinner();
        }
    }
var n;
var m;

function checkWinner(){
        var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
        for (var n=0; n<i; n++) {
            for (var m=0; m<j; m++) {
                if (kvadratiki[n][m] == kvadratiki[n+1][m+1] && 'x') {
                    alert('X WINS')
                } 
            }
        }
};

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Поле 3 на 3, при нажатии - ставится крестик или нолик, по правилам игры хочу сделать проверку, если в ряд, в столбик, или по диагонали крестики или нолики - выводить алерт. Допустим поле n-ное, оно может быть 3 на 3 или 100 на 100. Хочу сделать проверку.
К примеру поле 3 на 3, получается поле ij:

```
00 01 02
10 11 12
20 21 22
```

- вроде правильно обозначил, 
  не могу догнать как вытащить из этого массива на проверку элементы типа (по диагонали) - [0][0], [1][1], [2][2], получается здесь [i][j],[i+1][j+1] и так далее, беру в учет, если квадратов много.
  ну и наподобие в ряд или столбик:
  [i][j], [i][j+1]
  [i][j], [i+1][j]

Comment: у вас сейчас работаёт? в чём именно главная проблема?

Comment: нет, алерт же не выводится )

Comment: в чём именно главная проблема?) а то сложновато для понимания

Comment: эм, так я же описал все детально, я не знаю что еще добавить

Comment: есть массив [i][j], мне нужно обратиться к элементам  [i][j],[i+1][j+1] и так далее

Comment: у вас он даже не заполняется вроде) мне выводит что длинны нету

Comment: всё заполняется)

Comment: ну в функции checkWinners у вас даже циклы не запускаются

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yweGWtfJwEeOkot5ejsW?p=preview      что там не запускается

Comment: все не запускается я уже код скопировал разбираюсь) у вас i и j равны undefined (0) по этому и не запускается. Но тут надо вообще все перерабатывать

Comment: так проблема и есть в checkWinners, что значит даже ?))))) все работает кроме неё

Comment: вы объявили i и j и не дали никакого значения вот и не идут циклы. но даже если пойдут оно там не выведет там проверка даже не проходит. тут нужно всю логику поменять я пока даже не знаю как.

Comment: для i j есть циклы, они создали эти 9 квадратов ))

Comment: эти переменные идут только в цикл и больше никуда. а вы перед ними создали 2 переменные без значений. тогда надо убрать с циклов var

Comment: кажись еще проблема в том, что крестики и нолики рисуются в общем блоке game, а не отдельно в каждом блоке

Answer (score 1):

Для главной диагонали:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    /* Некие действия с элементом kvadratiki[i][i]; */
}
```

Для побочной диагонали:

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
     /* Некие действия с элементом kvadratiki[i][n-i-1]; */
}
```

Comment: i<n ? изначально там i, значения n то нету, или я не понимаю, еще вопрос как обратиться потом к элементам этим по диагонали, чтобы вывести алерт

Comment: NxN размер вашего поля.  - "Допустим поле n-ное".
Как обойти диагональные элементы - я написал выше. Проверка на то, что они все принадлежат какому-то игроку ничем не отличается от случая, когда вы рассматриваете строку/столбец.

Comment: поле n-ное значит может быть клеток 3 на 3 а мб 100 на 100, поле у меня ij, вы код читали ?))

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, зачем вам 2 переменные, если поле "n-ное".
Как обратиться к каждому диагональному элементу уже было написано. 
Ну и зачем вам в данному фрагменте  if (kvadratiki[n][m] == kvadratiki[n+1][m+1] && 'x') условие 'x'. Оно всегда true.

Comment: как всегда, там или х или 0.

Comment: двухмерный массив , вот и 2 переменные, ладно, плохо объяснился, как обратиться к нему  если  диагональ имеет 'x' в блоке

Comment: а если одну переменную, то если поле будет 100 на 100, как мне поймать диагональ или ряд или столбик))

Answer (score 1):

**Вот рабочий пример на основе вашего кода. Размер поля не имеет значения и может изменяться в переменной `gameFieldSize`**

[Пример игры](https://codepen.io/Dimas_X/pen/eKjmRZ?editors=1000)

**Работает для столбцов и строк. Попробуйте сами дописать логику для отлавливания диагоналей.**

В цикле создания сетки в каждый хтмл блок добавлен атрибут координат.

```
document.getElementById('game')
            .innerHTML+='<div class="block" data-coordinates = '+ i + j +'></div>';
```

Затем получаем эти координаты и запихиваем в соответствующую ячейку массива `kvadratiki` ноль или единицу

```
if (move%2==0) {
   event.target.innerHTML = 'x';
   var coordinates = event.target.getAttribute('data-coordinates').split('');
   kvadratiki[coordinates[0]][coordinates[1]] = 1;
}
```

Дальше передаем эти же координаты в ф-ю `checkWinner(coordinates);`
и проверяем строку и столбец.

```
        var checkRow = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < gameFieldSize; i++) {
          checkRow.push(kvadratiki[coordinates[0]][i]);
        }
        if(checkRow.every(e => e === 1)){
          alert('X win the game!');
          return;
        }else if(checkRow.every(e => e === 0)) {
          alert('0 win the game!');
          return; 
        }
```

Сама сетка рисуется динамически, поэтому если изменяете размер сетки в переменной `gameFieldSize` то получаем размер одного квадратика и умножаем на размер поля, затем задаем размеры самого поля, чтоб корректно выводилось в ХТМЛ

```
var blockSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.block'),null).getPropertyValue("height");
    document.querySelector('#game').style.width =  gameFieldSize * parseInt(blockSize) + 15 + 'px';
    document.querySelector('#game').style.height =  gameFieldSize * parseInt(blockSize) + 15 + 'px';
```